# Minimal number of nodes to connect a given set of nodes

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-optimization, graph-connectivity

Let $G=(V,E)$ be an undirected graph and let $U \subset V$. Is there an algorithm that could find a minimal set of nodes that need to be added to $U$ so that the subgraph generated by the added nodes and nodes in $U$ is connected?

I know that such a set of added nodes is not usually unique. If finding such a set is very slow or almost impossible in big graphs, is there a way to a find such a set that it is quite close to being minimal?

Answer (score 1):

This is known as the [Steiner tree problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem#Steiner_tree_in_graphs_and_variants). Note that minimizing vertices or edges is the same, since the number of vertices of a steiner tree is $e+1-c$ (where $c$ is the number of connected components in the graph induced by $|U|$, and not counting edges between vertices of $U $)

This is a NP-hard problem, but you can find some good approximation results (see the link)